# Codename One: iOS Screenshot/Splash Screen on Android

Tags: android, ios, codenameone

I've read the "[The iOS Screenshot/Splash Screen Process](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html#section-ios-screenshots)" on the Codename One manual. It's interesting.

My question is if it's possible to get a similar functionality on Android, in a portable manner.

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Android has too many resolutions/densities. This process exists since iOS requires those screenshots (or a xib file in newer versions). So it's there to support a native requirement of the OS that doesn't exist in Android.